# I LOST MY FUND EVEN ALREADY IMPORT WALLET

Tags: copay

I cannot recover my fund in Copay Wallet. I done import wallet using my back up 12 phrase word but yet still cannot recover. Why?

Answer (score 3):

- Check the wallet version, was it copay the wallet you initiated the seed from? If not, the derivation path for your coins may be different, please check: https://walletsrecovery.org/
- They've changed multisig derivation few times, I think there is a link to recovery tool for older versions.
- Be aware that your mnemonic is dependant on the arrangement of the words, they have to be imported in the direction from 1st to 12th.